# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS running dead slow on Dell PowerEdge R900

Tags: dell

I want to install and use Ubuntu on my Dell PowerEdge R900 but the OS is lagging way too much. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you install it or are you running it from a stick drive?

Answer (score 0):

Dell PowerEdge R900 is a server. I think it has powerful hardware for server purposes, but a very simple graphics chip/card for the console. If you run standard Ubuntu, it will struggle displaying the graphical desktop environment.

- Either install Ubuntu Server and use it as a server, maybe mainly via remote access (`ssh`).
- Or install a graphics card that is powerful enough for Ubuntu's desktop environment.